# Rearranging the tab order of fields in a sub form in data sheet view

Tags: ms-access, vba, access-control

This is an ongoing problem, and I'm hoping there is just a property that I'm missing.

Scenario: I have a form that contains subforms. The Default View property for the subforms is set to Datasheet. (The main form is set to Single Form). Due to changes in what I'm tracking, I want to include another field that wasn't part of the original record source. So, I changed the record source (a query) and added the field to the subform. The new field is added to the end of the Datasheet view by default.

Here is the problem - when I drag the column to a new location on the subform (in Form view or Layout view), it does not stay put. I have made the change using Form view and Layout view, and I've changed the Tab Index property for the field to the proper number.  The new position never stays on the first, or second, sometimes third and fourth try. I have tried saving in Form view, Layout view and Design view, but I always have to drag the column back to the new position and try to save again . This goes on until Access actually saves the change. drag, save, didn't take; drag, save, didn't take; drag...

What I'd like to know is this - how do I rearrange columns on a form that is set to "Datasheet" for the Default View property, and make it stick the first time?

Thanks for any suggestions - I must be missing something....

Comment: Have you tried to change the position of that field in the query(The recordsource) itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known "limitation" of datasheets. Some want the columns fit or preset, other sticky, some either as selected by the user.

To control the order of the columns, adjust the `ColumnOrder` property of the displayed controls.

Comment: Thank you. Precisely the answer I was looking for.