# Reset the Microsoft Access query column order to match the SQL after they've been re-ordered in Datasheet view?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Datasheet View of a Microsoft Access query, if the columns are re-ordered by dragging them around, they no longer follow the order defined in the underlying Access SQL. If the column order is changed in the SQL, the order in the Datasheet no longer follows. Even if the order is dragged back to match the SQL, it still won't begin following the SQL again. The order of the columns in Datasheet View has essentially become disconnected from the SQL and is stuck in "manual mode".

How can this be reset so the column order in Datasheet View begins following the SQL again?

I've searched StackOverflow and Google for the answer to this, but found none.

Note: I'm highly fluent in Access VBA, so if anyone knows of a static or transient property for this buried deep in the properties collection of the query, I can work with that. Thanks.

Comment: Review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa224067(v=office.11). However, that code example is changing column order of a table. I don't know if can be done with query. Maybe should use a form set for Datasheet, not a query object. Then VBA to open a recordset of query, loop through fields by index to get field name and apply column order. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283908/rearranging-the-tab-order-of-fields-in-a-sub-form-in-data-sheet-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each field in your `QueryDef`, set the field's `.Properties("ColumnOrder").Value = 0`

Here is an example in the Immediate window.  I had manually moved the first column into the last position on the datasheet and saved the query with that layout.

```vb
? CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryBase").Fields.Count
 3 

for i = 0 to 2 : ? CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryBase").Fields(i).Properties("ColumnOrder").Value : next
 3 
 1 
 2
```

Changing *ColumnOrder* to 0 causes Access to use the querydef's SQL to determine the column order for datasheet view:

```vb
for i = 0 to 2 : CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryBase").Fields(i).Properties("ColumnOrder").Value = 0 : next

for i = 0 to 2 : ? CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryBase").Fields(i).Properties("ColumnOrder").Value : next
 0 
 0 
 0
```

Comment: It works, but why doesn't the for-loop `for i = 0 to (CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryBase").Fields.Count -1)` gives me a Run-Time error '3270: Property not found' I substracted 1 to be same as the index.

Comment: I seem to recall `ColumnOrder` is hidden & transient. Meaning it can't be accessed directly like `object.ColumnOrder=1`. It can only be accessed through the Properties collection as `.Properties("ColumnOrder")`. AND it doesn't exist unless previously written to. Also, I seem to recall there's no built-in VBA function to check if a property exists. You have to spin your own for-each loop to go through the `.Properties` collection to check the `.Name` property (of each property) to look for `"ColumnOrder"` (clean), or crash out into an error handler with `On Error` (messy).